# Gulp livereload doesn't work with gulp-connect using watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, livereload

I'm using `gulp-connect` plugin for my development server and also I've installed `gulp-livereload`. Then I made the following tasks:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');


gulp.task('serve', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: 'app',
    livereload: true
  });
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
  gulp.src('./app/stylesheets/*.css')
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src('./app/index.html')
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./app/stylesheets/*.css', ['css']);
  gulp.watch('./app/index.html', ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve', 'watch']);
```

But whenever I run the server and make any changes to stylesheets or `index.html` I still need to refresh the page manually, though I've made everything according to their docs. I've tried also to write the `default` task like this:

```
gulp.task('default', ['serve', 'html', 'css', 'watch']);
```

but it didn't help either. What is the problem with livereload?

**ADDED:** When I check the console, it says that it cannot connect to `ws://localhost:35729/livereload`. Also when I refresh the page, console says that connection with `ws://localhost:35729/livereload` was interrupted. Does that mean that livereload cannot establish proper connection?

**EDIT:** Though I've done nothing, now livereload does refresh the page automatically, when I change my `.css` file. But it still doesn't refresh when I change `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My very, very bad -- I've just now noticed, that in my original code I had

```
// ...
  gulp.watch('./app/html', ['html']);
```

instead of line from above. As soon as I fixed it, everything worked!